# Can we close ambiguously tagged questions as “unclear what you are asking?”

Tags: discussion, tags, vote-to-close, unclear

I'm a C programmer who loves to answer questions about C programming. I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to C++ though and as C and C++ have subtle differences even when it comes to the overlapping parts of the two languages, I do not like to answer C++ questions lest my answer is incorrect.

Many beginners for some reason tag their questions as both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and it's not always clear what language they are programming in. To avoid writing a wrong or useless answer, I want to be certain that they are interested in an answer about C before answering. If I can't figure out what language they use from the code they are asking about, I proceed to ask what language they are programming in.

If I don't receive an answer to this question in a timely manner, is it appropriate to close the question as “unclear what you are asking?”

Comment: Better decide to remove one of the tags. Most often, these questions decide for one based on the code that's shown.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do this (please **read** the post before commenting; I already say that I try to guess based on the code shown), this question pertains the cases where it's not possible to do so.

Comment: If it's not possible, then closing as unclear is fine IMHO.

Comment: Here's an excellent candidate from today: [Will DLL Block freeze my Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081932/will-dll-block-freeze-my-application)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If only one of them makes sense (using implicit conversion from `void*`, `templates`, or anything else only part of *one* of the language), or there is anything else unambiguously marking which language is used, correct the tags.

Otherwise, if the question doesn't make it clear that it's double-tagged for a valid reason, close it as unclear, because that's what it is.

Comment: This ^^^. A side note, *most* of the valid reasons to have both tags have been asked before, and have really great canonical answers that the question author would probably appreciate. *If* you have a few minutes to hunt, it's nice to point them out, since they probably eluded the asker.

Comment: You need to be careful about just assuming based on the code though. Beginners often don't know some of the finer differences between the languages, and they can't often count on the compiler to help them in that matter. For example, g++ will, by default, accept variable length arrays without warning.

Answer (score 3):

The tags that users put on questions are often suggested by Stack Overflow itself.  This is particularly true for people who are new to the site.

I see this problem with the MySQL tag being applied to numerous questions for other databases.  This is almost never the idea of the OP; they are typically accepting a tag suggested to them.

Before voting to close such a question, ask the OP for clarification.  In the case of C/C++.  I suppose if there is no response after some time period, you can vote to close it.  But definitely ask first.  You can even feel free to answer the question, clarifying that your answer is specific to C and not to C++.

Comment: Well, it can be reopened. But as those votes are limited and the queue is far too long, if it seems likely you'l get a timely response and you have the time and inclination to babysit the post, commenting first is ok.

Comment: @Deduplicator . . . Why would you add something to the close queue before trying to rectify it with the OP?

Comment: Well, as I wrote, if you have time and inclination to babysit it, commenting and waiting is fine, and probably better because the queue is too full. But if you won't stay on it, vote now instead of never.

Comment: I don't like writing an answer under assumptions because quite often it ends up not being what OP expects and I'm either downvoted or ignored, both of which are things I don't like when writing answers.

Comment: @FUZxxl . . . I don't see why an answer that clearly specifies that it is for C would be downvoted on a question that has a "C" tag.  Of course, people are free to downvote whatever they want, but the behavior seems nasty.